# Configuring Apex_Email in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am finding it difficult to configure email in Oracle Apex 5 with the available resources online. The oracle documentation for the Apex email set up is for the older versions of apex (4.2, 3 etc) which has **Manage Instance feature.** This feature is not available for the Apex 5.

I will appreciate it if you can help me set up APex_Mail in **Oracle Apex 5**
Thanks 

**NB.There is no "MANAGE INSTANCE FEATURE IN APEX 5**

Comment: RTM: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39151/adm_wrkspc003.htm#AEADM29189

Comment: and: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39151/adm_login.htm#AEADM168